# import aws from 'aws-sdk' node crashing

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

I'm trying to get aws sdk to play nice with .ts files. 
When I try to import it its fine but then when I try to use anything from that import it crashes my node.

> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Example:

```
import aws from 'aws-sdk';

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});
```

I have @types/node installed and working fo all other modules.

Comment: what is the main error?

Comment: Thats the problem it's not showing an error only crashing the app. If I use require its fine but I want to use import not require

Comment: Just start your with "native" nodejs command like `node index.js` (or `ts-node index.ts` for typescript), maybe it will show you what happend...

Comment: this is still happening here... any updates?

Comment: This is happening to me when a container is run in Fargate, but not local.  Very frustrating.  Switching the single `import` to `require` fixes it though